# How to access data in an array based on user input, java

Tags: java, arrays, excel

I have searched around but I mostly find information on how to place user input into an array. I am basically looking for the reverse. I want to make a two dimensional array based off of a table that has 22 rows and 15 columns. The rows are temperature and the columns are a distance. I would like the user to input a temperature and a distance and then be provided with the appropriate value from the predefined table (that I will code as an array).

Simplified, I have a table of data in excel that I want to transform into code (as an array I assume) and allow the user to enter a row and column value and be presented with the corresponding cell value.

Comment: There is nothing in Java to enter whole array at once, must make loop. Interfacing with excel is other story.

Comment: You can retrieve the values of the two dimensional arrays as: yourArrayName[temperature][distance]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to put all the data into an array. You just need to pass the temperature and distance to a function that will then do a lookup or search through a range and return your value.

Or if you want to return multiple answers if you have duplicated data then you will need an array to store the answers from the table. Please explain do you have duplicated data or not and I will write the excel code to retrieve the data.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there is duplicated data and I can't seem to derive an equation from it. There are too many outliers. If I could, then I could just skip the table all together and have the program run the user input (temp, distance) through the equation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Charlie, let me get this straight you have an array two dimensional with rows equating to temperature and columns equating to distance. You want the user to enter both distance and temperature and the answer from the array to be returned. My question to you is are there more that one answer and even if there is it is not a big problem just display all the answers. Is this something that you are looking for in Java or in VBA? Then why did you mention you have a table in excel?